# Migrate from SQL to MongoDB?

Tags: sql-server, mongodb, migration

I am researching on the possibilities of migrating data from SQL 2012 to mongoDB. And my manager specifically asked me to see the time it takes to process billions of rows in SQL and MongoDB to make a decision to migrate or not. Any recommendations or suggestions or places I should visit to research more?
So far I have done

1. installed MongoDB in my development environment
2. i have been able to connect to MongoDB, created Databases and collections

Questions I have now
 3. how to import the database in SQL to Mongo (say migrate Adventure Works)

Thanks In Advance!

Comment: Have you seen this [Mongify](http://mongify.com/)

Comment: Thanks much Nicolas. It seems the right tool to my situation. I will explore it more and see if that will work for me.     But it looks like Mongify does not work for Windows? Any ideas on that Nicolas?

Comment: How come? Where does it state that?

Comment: i was researching earlier. But here is a solution I found. https://mssql2mongo.codeplex.com/ ..... this tool helped me migrate just one table. And now I am about to try migrating related tables and see the result.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Some best practices I learned the hard way.

## Do a partial import

When planning a MongoDB cluster, you need to have an idea how big the average document size is. In order to do that, import some 10k records of your data. This gives you an idea on how long the actual import will take in orders of magnitude:

[image: time to migrate]

where t is the time it took to import n documents of c.

Repeat this for all target collections. After that, issue a

```
db.stats()
```

in the mongo shell. You will be presented with some size statistics.  You now have approximations to two key factors: the time it takes to import (by summing up the results of above calculation) and the storage space you will need.

## Create the indices on the partial import

Create the indices you are going to need. As for time calculations, the same as above applies. But there is a different thing: indices should reside in RAM, so you need to extrapolate the actual RAM you need when all records are migrated.

Chances are that it isn't cost efficient to store all data on one machine, since RAM is getting costly after a certain point (calculation are necessary here). If that is the case, you need to shard.

## When sharding: Choose a proper shard key

It can not be overemphasized how important it is to have a [proper shard key](http://docs.mongodb.org/master/tutorial/choose-a-shard-key/) right from the start: **Shard keys can not be changed**. Invest some time with the developers to find a proper shard key.

## When sharding: Pre-split chunks

The last thing you want during data migration is to have it being delayed by the [balancer](http://docs.mongodb.org/master/reference/glossary/#term-balancer) trying to balance out the chunks. So you should [pre-split your chunks](http://docs.mongodb.org/master/tutorial/create-chunks-in-sharded-cluster/) and distribute them among your shards.

Answer (score 5):

I've created a Node.js script that replicates an SQL database to MongoDB.

You can find it [here](https://github.com/ashleydavis/sql-to-mongodb).

To use...

**Clone the repo:**

```
git clone https://github.com/ashleydavis/sql-to-mongodb
```

**Install dependencies:**

```
cd sql-to-mongodb
npm install
```

**Setup your config:**

Edit config.js. Add your SQL connection string and details for your MongoDB database.

**Run the script:**

```
node index.js
```

This can take a while to complete! But when it does you will have a copy of your SQL database in MongoDB. Please let me know if there are any issues.

Comment: hello Ashley! Thanks a lot for your script. What would be the sqlConnectionString like?

I've tried a couple like:
```jdbc:mysql://user:pass@localhost:3306/dbname``` but an error is always returned: "Database replication errored out. TypeError: Invalid server: undefined". Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: What the connection string looks like depends on your database, I don't have any idea what you are using. Here's some help if it's Azure SQL: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/troubleshoot-common-errors-issues. Also not sure why you prefix with "jdbc" that is something to do with Java so it seems wrong here, but I'm not sure. If you can't figure out how to connect to your database maybe ask a question on this site. Good luck!

Comment: Thanks for your answer! It's a mySQL database, stored in local environment. What would be the sqlConnectionString in that case? I would like to give it a last try before asking a public question. Thanks!

Comment: Sorry I'm not sure. I've barely used MySQL.

Comment: Plenty of information online though, try googling "connection string for mysql database"